# Continue to listen for sound whenever I plug in or out my headset

Tags: windows-7, audio

My windows shows me 2 playback devices: internal speakers and headset.

When I change headset connectivity, I hear no sound at all.I have to exit from my media player and restart it.

I want continue to hear my sound whenever I plug in or plug out my headphones. What should I do with?

It is common problem, but I have not found any solution.

Comment: If you solved the problem, post the solution as an answer.

Comment: What's your sound hardware? If your uncertain, what type of computer are you using? There are some tricks to do this but many of them are hardware specific.

Comment: **Mark Szymanzski**, I can't put answers for my own questions, only comments

Comment: **Blomkvist**, I use Realtek hardware. and I've solved this with installing Realtek drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Realtek hardware. and I've solved this with installing Realtek drivers